# android zxing barcode scanning getting Bound mismatch

Tags: android, zxing

I am trying to compile zxing from the following link:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/checkout

but it dont get compile. its giving me following error:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method of(E, E...) of type EnumSet<E> is not applicable for the arguments (BarcodeFormat, BarcodeFormat, BarcodeFormat, BarcodeFormat). The inferred type BarcodeFormat is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Enum<E>>
```

I read the conversation between sean and riz at following link:

http://groups.google.com/group/zxing/browse_thread/thread/2c775d28da3c8454/ac2eb3b45cd3f9bd?show_docid=ac2eb3b45cd3f9bd

i didnt understand the meaning of

```
You should not be including 
CaptureActivity in your code. You should be including core.jar.
```

if i dont include core.jar , i will not be able to get

```
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat
```

so how can i fix this problem. i am trying to understand the code written by zxing author. i dont want to use intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this means you are not actually compiling the code you checked out from Subversion, since it definitely does compile. You probably mixed an old version of the `core/` library (which did not use `enum`) with a new version of the `android/` code, which does.

Comment: Yes perhaps i am doing the same which you are saying.so where i can get the latest core.jar file

Comment: You build it from the source you checked out. Run `ant` in `core/`

Comment: Thanks Brother. it really helps me to compile the code. well you guys used import android.provider.ContactsContract which is supported in API LEVEL 5(Android 2.0) so how it will support android 1.6?

Comment: The project has required Android 2.1 since about November.

Comment: But you were saying that it will support 1.5 also?

Comment: Yes, it did support Android 1.5 until about revision 2030 in Subversion. You can check out as of that rev, or use ZXing 1.7, which is older.